# Juniper EX3200: Is there SDM templates as in Cisco?

Tags: juniper

Cisco has "sdm templates" and the number of mac, arp, ace, route entires depends on template type. Is there something like that in Juniper switches?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such command, because juniper support features out-of-the-box, without TCAM refragmentation, as in Cisco.

Comment: I believe you are correct that there is no equivalent, but I am certain JunOS has a ton of tuning options. Check out the the ethernet-switching section of the configuration, looks like there are plenty of per-interface options. I can tell you that unless that EX3200 is a core switch with a few hundred other switches connected you're probably not going to overwhelm it for resources.